# Problem sort numbers (currency )with thousands, millions and billions

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I have a problem to sort a table in ascending and descending order. Need your help!!! I have numbers from 0,0000000052€ till 31.939€. Here is my tablesort.js, how can i solve this problem any ideas. My target is to sort the table in ascending and descending order when i click the headers. For all help i am very grateful.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('th').each(function (col) {
    $(this).hover(
      function () {
        $(this).addClass('focus');
      },
      function () {
        $(this).removeClass('focus');
      }
    );
    $(this).click(function () {
      if ($(this).is('.asc')) {
        $(this).removeClass('asc');
        $(this).addClass('desc selected');
        sortOrder = -1;
      } else {
        $(this).addClass('asc selected');
        $(this).removeClass('desc');
        sortOrder = 1;
      }
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('asc selected');
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('desc selected');
      var arrData = $('table').find('tbody >tr:has(td)').get();
      arrData.sort((a, b) => {
        var val1 = $(a).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
        parseFloat(val1);

        var val2 = $(b).children('td').eq(col).text().toUpperCase();
        parseFloat(val2);

        if ($.isNumeric(val1) && $.isNumeric(val2))
          return sortOrder == 1 ? val1 - val2 : val2 - val1;
        else return val1 < val2 ? -sortOrder : val1 > val2 ? sortOrder : 0;
      });
      $.each(arrData, function (index, row) {
        $('tbody').append(row);
      });
    });
  });
});

//Example ejs File
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') -%>

<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
    <table
      id="myTable"
      class="mdl-data-table table table-sortable mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table mdl-shadow"
    >
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__header-cell--sorted">Kurs</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="coinTable">
        <tr>
          <td class="current_price">0,0000234</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="current_price">9,99</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="current_price">31780,86</td>
        </tr>

        <script src="javascripts/tablesort.js"></script>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>``
```

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the HTML table you're trying to sort, along with some demo values in the column.

Comment: i take the numbers from my mongodb with a loop but i include a example table

Comment: This line `if ($.isNumeric(val1) && $.isNumeric(val1))` looks incorrect

Comment: Also, you are using `parseFloat(..)` but don't you need to assign the return value to a variable?

Comment: If you're using `parseFloat` then note that it *requires* US-/western-centric locale.  eg `"31393"` for 31 thousand.  `"31.393"` (dot thousand separator) will be 31 point 3 (considers `"."` a decimal point) and `"31,393"` (comma thousand separator) will be "31" (commas not recognised).

Comment: The simplest solution for sorting is to separately store the "decimal" value and display the locale value, eg `<td data-value="31393.20">31.393,20</td>` (depending on locale for thousand/decimal separator).  Then sort/parseFloat the data value, not the displayed text.

Comment: ok i understand it but i don't know how to implement it. Can you make an example of how I can address it in the tablesort

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for help. I found a way that works for me. Sure it is not the best way but it works fine and fast. I optimized my tablesort, here my solution.

````
        var val1 = $(a)
          .children('td')
          .eq(col)
          .text()
          .toUpperCase()
          .replace(/[.]/g, '')
          .replace(/[_]/g, '0.0')
          .replace(/[,]/g, '.');
        var val3 = parseFloat(val1);```
````